# How to use SDL2 inside another GUI toolkit window?

Tags: c++, qt, sdl, wxwidgets

Is there anyway to embed a SDL2 "window" inside a cross-platform GUI toolkit (like Qt, wxWidgets, etc.) window?

The goal is to have some other controls in the main window, things like zoom, save, color selection, etc. which will control the SDL window, like emulators do, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can [get SDL window's system handle](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-tip-window-handle), and than re-parent it into your application window. This is platform-specific, however.